# Ionic é indicado para quais tipos de aplicativos?

Tags: java, apache-cordova, objective-c, ionic

O *Ionic Framework* é indicado para quais tipos de aplicações? Venho fazendo algumas pesquisas sobres os plugins do *cordova*, parece dar muito problema no desenvolvimento multiplataforma, alguns plugins não funcionam bem para o *IOS* e *Windows Phone*? A melhor opção é ir para o nativo?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O Ionic é muito utilizado para aplicativos que não requerem muita animação ou processamento gráfico. Utilizo bastante para aplicativos como loja virtual, chat, portifolio, catalogo, etc.
Conheço várias empresas que estão migrando do desenvolvimento nativo para plataformas híbridas. Primeiro pela sua facilidade em manutenção e desenvolvimento, segundo pela sua maturidade e confiabilidade nos dias atuais.

Comment: E para aplicações mais robustas que consomem a maioria dos recursos nativos do aparelho, como GPS, push, contatos, captura de audio e etc...
Você acha que compensa usar o framework ou partir para o nativo?
E o nosso maior problema seria usar um webService SOAP+XML, e vi que para isso teria que fazer uma conversão do xml para json. @Fabio Nobre

Comment: Isso depende muito, eu particularmente prefiro nativo, pois tem maior controle sobre o código e novidades lançadas no SDK do dispositivo, tem mais bibliotecas e seu aplicativo ficará mais leve.. Mas claro isso deve ser levando em consideração a complexidade do projeto, se for algo simples não vejo problema ao usar os softwares de  _cross platform_

Comment: Obrigado @MarcoGiovanni  por esclarecer, o que projeto que iremos desenvolver ele é bem complexo, e fiquei de fazer testes nos recursos nativos usando o ionic. Mas no entando estamos chegando na conclusão que a melhor opção será ir para o nativo.

Answer (score 5):

Algumas funcionalidades nativas do celular ainda não estão disponíveis nas bibliotecas Cordova Apache, caso seu projeto não faça uso de nenhuma vá fundo. Super recomendo!
Com relação a desempenho, não tenho do que reclamar!
Existe uma biblioteca crosswalk que promete melhorar perfomance de celulares android do 4 ao 4.4 faço uso delas.

Uma informação importante é que algumas bibliotecas tem implementações diferentes para cada plataforma por isso vocẽ deve ter ouvido que alguém teve problema com essa ou aquele SO Mobile, mas em via de regras, consulte antes a documentação que não tem erro.

Boa sorte!

Comment: Poderia citar quais são essas funcionalidades que não estão disponíveis no Cordova?

Answer (score 0):

O Ionic é indicado para aplicações relativamente mais simples. Por exemplo, se você tentar criar algo parecido com um Instagram ou Facebook, terá problemas de desempenho no Ionic por conta dos vários import necessário entre outros.