# Qual é a diferença entre o Apache Cordova e o Ionic?

Tags: android, ionic, apache-cordova

Tenho algumas dúvidas referente ao Apache Cordova e o Ionic. Ambos, para mim, parecem a mesma coisa com o mesmo propósito, permitir a criação de aplicações hibridas para dispositivos mobile.

Veja que no [site do Ionic](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/guide/installation.html) é necessário ter o Cordova instalado para que o Ionic funcione. Portanto, é neste ponto que surgem as minhas dúvidas.

## Dúvidas

1. Qual é a diferença do Apache Cordova e relação ao Ionic?
2. O que faz com que um seja dependente do outro para criar aplicações
   híbridas?

Comment: Algumas que podem ajudar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/170138/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/79939/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/153243/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/174598/10 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/130973/101

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Resumidamente, o [Apache Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) é responsável por fazer seu código Javascript acessar **recursos nativos** do dispositivo, como câmera, GPS, acelerômetro, dentre outros. Já o [Ionic](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiIw4fP35vWAhXBipAKHdSJAPAQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fionicframework.com%2F&usg=AFQjCNFs_Vi2jRGpAkX2cqIN0vXtw-ERgA) é um *framework* que cuida da parte visual da aplicação, da forma como ela será apresentada para o usuário final, criando aparências muito similares ao de aplicações nativas.

Como, suponho eu que já tenha lido, o Ionic foi construído sobre o Cordova, que é a camada inferior, responsável por cuidar da parte de transformação do aplicativo em pacotes para cada sistema operacional.

Veja abaixo uma comparação usando o mesmo código, porém compilados para IOS e Android.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Perceba que o Ionic faz o tratamento do código para deixar a aparência de acordo com o sistema que você usa, sendo ele Android, iOS, etc.

O Apache Cordova trabalha com outros *frameworks* além do Ionic, como [jQuery Mobile](https://jquerymobile.com/), [Dojo Mobile](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/mobile.html), [Sencha Touch](https://www.sencha.com/products/touch/), [Lungo](https://github.com/tapquo/Lungo.js/), [Mobile Angular UI](http://mobileangularui.com/).

A conclusão é que são duas ferramentas diferentes, dependentes, sendo o Cordova uma ponte para tratar da comunicação com *hardware*, funcionando como "*backend*" e o Ionic para trabalhar em questões de aparência para o usuário final, como "*frontend*".

Comment: E o Phonegap tem alguma coisa a ver com estes caras?

Comment: @LINQ O projeto Phonegap, que também já foi chamado de *Apache Callback* e *Apache DeviceReady*,  passou a ser o atual Apache Cordova depois de alguns anos. Já o Adobe Phonegap como diz no [próprio site do Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/), é a distribuição mas popular do Apache Cordova, que também atua como *backend*. O Apache Cordova  é o motor que alimenta o Adobe PhoneGap. [Essa imagem](http://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/art_wargo3_phonegap/elementLinks/wargo3_fig01.jpg) ilustra bem o que aconteceu.

Comment: @LINQ como o autor ressaltou somente a questão da relação entre Ionic e Cordova, não vi motivo para falar sobre o Phonegap na resposta. Mas é interessante o histórico. =D

Comment: Show, obrigado pela explicação. Eu sei que ele não perguntou e tal, mas eu fiquei curioso porque sempre me confundo quando falam de um ou de outro. Valeu novamente pela explicação.

Answer (score 8):

[Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) é o projeto aberto base de criação de aplicativos híbridos para mobile. Ele utiliza tecnologias web (HTML, CSS, JS) para criar aplicações para celulares e outros dispositivos, mas que não rodam em um *browser* normal como um site. Os recursos do dispositivo ficam acessíveis, ao contrário de um site normal.

Ionic é uma extensão do Cordova usando [AngularJS](http://ionicframework.com/) preferindo [TypeScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15998/101) do que JavaScript. Isto permite que a formatação visual seja muito mais rica e facilitada (embora há quem discorde que seja mais fácil), seu foco é a UI tentando abstrair as diferenças de cada plataforma e não cuidar do acesso aos recursos do dispositivo.

Há uma dúvida recorrente e adjacente sobre o [PhoneGap](https://phonegap.com/) que é o Cordova estendido pela Adobe.

Elas não são concorrentes, são complementares.

Mais informações:

- [React Native ou Ionic?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/170138/101)
- [Quando utilizar Cordova ou Xamarin?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/79939/101)
- [Ionic é indicado para quais tipos de aplicativos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/153243/101)
- [Qual a linguagem de programação para criar aplicações Android?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/174598/10)
- [Aplicação MVC ou SPA](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/130973/101)

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28256607/221800).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Other/Conceptual.md).