# App - Xamarin ou Ionic?

Tags: c#, ionic, xamarin

Preciso criar um App e gostaria de saber qual das tuas tecnologias é a mais indicada pra desenvolvimento mobile.

- Qual a principal diferença entre Xamarin e Ionic?
- Qual das tecnologias é a mais performática?
- Por que usar Ionic ? Por que não usar ?
- Por que usar Xamarin? Por que não usar ?

Aceito indicações de outras tecnologias.

Comment: Relacionado ou duplicata: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/236145/101

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Qual a principal diferença entre Xamarin e Ionic?

A ideia do `Xamarin` é o desenvolvimento `cross-plataform` nativo, ou seja, ao gerar os aplicativos, são gerados aplicativos nativos para cada plataforma, seja IOS, Android ou até aplicativos windows. A principal diferença é que com o `Xamarin` os aplicativos são desenvolvidos a partir do `.NET Framework` com `C#`. Outra vantagem é quanto a interface, cada plataforma tem suas guidelines([Android](https://developer.android.com/design/?hl=pt-br) e [IOS](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/overview/themes)) e o `Xamarin` irá gerar as interfaces respeitando cada uma delas, um exemplo é o menu, que em cada plataforma, por padrão fica em um lugar (Android em cima e IOS em baixo). A desvantagem do `Xamarin` é que apenas 75% do "código de interface" pode ser compartilhado entre as plataformas, ou seja, nos outros 25% é necessário a criação de visualizações para cada plataforma.

A ideia do `Ionic` também é um desenvolvimento multiplataforma, só que voltado apenas para IOS e Android, seu diferencial é a utilização de componentes Web no desenvolvimento (HTML, CSS e JavaScript) e utiliza um esquema de WebView para execução.

> Qual das tecnologias é a mais performática?

Em termos de desempenho o `Xamarin` ganha, só que, vou complementar a resposta com uma "provocação", cada vez mais essa diferença tende a diminuir a medida que as tecnologias avançam, dependendo do que deseja fazer, chega a ser imperceptível para o usuário a diferença de velocidade.

> Por que usar Ionic ? Por que não usar?

Velocidade de desenvolvimento, se a equipe já tem conhecimento Web, terá um gigante ganho de velocidade no desenvolvimento, em aplicativos que não usam muitos recursos do celular (quando digo recursos, não digo acesso a itens "nativos" porque hoje o `Ionic` já consegue acessar 99.9% dos recursos), em termos de processamento local. 
Aplicativos simples que irão apenas consumir apis, ou trazer visualizações para o usuário, com pouca intenção, também há ganho.
Custo menor que aplicativos em `Xamarin` ou nativos

Não usar quando for fazer aplicativos de jogos, aplicativos que irão consumir algum processamento e memoria.

> Por que usar Xamarin? Por que não usar ?

Se a equipe conhecer as tecnologias de desenvolvimento, também há ganho no desenvolvimento.
Aplicativos que serão multiplataforma
Aplicativos que consumirão determinado processamento

Não usar quando o aplicativo não for multiplataforma.
Dependendo do tempo que tiver, pode haver uma curva de aprendizado, o que pode ser um fator para não usar a tecnologia

Um adendo, segundo os guidelines, caso o desenvolvimento do aplicativo seja para apenas 1 plataforma (IOS ou Android) é aconselhado o desenvolvimento nativo na plataforma nativa.

<sub>Leituras recomendadas de comparativos(Todas estão em inglês):
[Leitura 1](https://belitsoft.com/react-native-development/react-native-vs-xamarin-vs-ionic), [Leitura 2](https://www.altexsoft.com/blog/engineering/xamarin-vs-react-native-vs-ionic-cross-platform-mobile-frameworks-comparison/), [Leitura 3](https://cruxlab.com/blog/reactnative-vs-xamarin/), 
[Leitura 4](https://www.iflexion.com/blog/cross-platform-development-wars-xamarin-vs-ionic/)</sub>

Answer (score 4):

> Qual a principal diferença entre Xamarin e Ionic?

**Xamarin:**
 É possível desenvolver apps móveis nativas escrevendo em C# tanto para IOS quanto para Android.

**Ionic:**
App é hibrida, roda dentro de um browser e utilza html, css e javascript. Na minha opinião só usaria caso o app não precisasse utilizar nada de recursos nativos.

**Por que usar Ionic?**
Ele é produtivo, é rapido o desenvolvimento e as apps ficam bonitas como na web.

**Por que não usar?**
Performace é lenta e possui recursos nativos limitados.

**Por que usar Xamarin?** 
App realmente fica nativa e com uma performance nativa.

**Por que não usar ?**
Talvez não saiba C# e tenha que dedicar um tempo para estudar e gasta mais tempo com o desenvolvimento.