# O que significa dizer que, um app é WebView? Qual a relação com Xamarin?

Tags: mobile, xamarin, xamarin-forms, webview, progressive-web-apps

Iniciando estudos em um projeto Xamarin, encontrei uma série de nomenclaturas e algumas explicações que parecem contraditórias, então tenho algumas dúvidas:

1. Ouvi dizer que Xamarin e Xamarin.Forms, **NÃO** são WebView, que na verdade eles geram *apps* nativos. Por outro lado já ouvi que podem utilizar WebView. Alguém pode me explicar mais sobre isso?
2. O que é PWA e qual sua relação com Xamarin? e outras tecnologias?
3. Se utilizar WebView ou tecnologias como Cordova ou Ionic, que tipos de recursos não conseguirei implementar?

Referências de pesquisa sobre esse assunto, será extremamente importante!

Comment: Relacionada: [O que são Progressive Web Apps?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/153860/91)

Comment: O xamarin é a plataform de desenvolvimento, xamarin forms é o frame que ajuda na criação de apps. Basicamente o xamarin faz o mapeamento de APIs do iOS e android através de abstrações.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Ouvi dizer que Xamarin e Xamarin.Forms, NÃO são WebView, que na verdade eles geram apps nativos. Por outro lado, já ouvi que podem utilizar WebView. Alguém pode me explicar mais sobre isso?

Significa que tudo feito no Xamarin usa a API do sistema operacional que está rodando, ou do Android ou do iOS. Não tem intermediários, então todo acesso é feito de forma direta sem passar por um *browser*, mesmo que seja um "sem a cabeça". Mas se precisar que alguma parte específica rode com tecnologias web pode ser um controle `WebView` que entrega o que precisa só naquele ponto. O PWA roda todo em um `WebView`, ele depende do *core* navegador para executar e interagir com o usuário, a API é web.

> O que é PWA e qual sua relação com Xamarin? E outras tecnologias?

Já respondido em [O que são Progressive Web Apps?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/153860/101). Não há relação com Xamarin, eles são concorrentes indiretos.

> Se utilizar WebView ou tecnologias como Cordova ou Ionic, que tipos de recursos não conseguirei implementar?

Isso é um pouco amplo de responder e pode mudar conforme a versão. Hoje tem pouca limitação efetiva já que é possível usar *plugins*. Muda um pouco o consumo maior de recursos.

Veja mais em [App - Xamarin ou Ionic?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/294519/101).

Não é objetivo do site oferecer referências de estudo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).